# compactly generate list of list python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have to create a list of lists (each inner list has `n` fixed elements). Right now, for `n=3` I am doing this:

```
my_list = []
for x in range(min_inner max_inner + 1):
    for y in range(min_outer, max_outer + 1):
        for z in range(fixed_param):
            my_list.append([x, y, z])
```

When I tried list comprehension, something like:

`[[x,y,z] for x in range(1,4), y in range(1,4), z in range (4)]`

I get a name error

`NameError: name 'z' is not defined`

Is there a list comprehension way of doing that? Considering that `n` can be any number (though not necessarily arbitrarily large)

Comment: Add for everywhere `[[x,y,z] for x in range(1,4) for y in range(1,4) for z in range (4)]` ...

Comment: Note that a comprehension just makes your code horizontal instead of vertical. Traditional loops are not automatically bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over your range objects inside the list comprehension too.

```
[[x,y,z] for x in range(1,4) for y in range(1,4) for z in range (4)]
```

Also as a more concise way you could use `itertools.product()` to achieve the same result:

```
from itertools import product    
list(product(range(1,4),range(1,4),range(4)))
```

Note that `itertools.product()` returns an iterator object which is pretty more optimized (in terms of memory usage) than list comprehension which returns a list. And if you just want to iterate over the result you don't need to convert the result to list. Otherwise the list comprehension will performs faster.

Comment: May be `[list(l) for l in product(range(1, 4), range(1, 4), range(1,4))]` if it should be the same as for first solution as list of lists

Comment: @AntonProtopopov In that case the list comprehension would be better. But if you mean, converting the tuples to list, yes it's a good approach too.

Comment: @Kasramvd the use of `product` from iter tools along with the converting to list from @Anton Protopopov  suits my need! thank you both :)